# How to insert selected variables by RFE into machine learning model in r?

Tags: r, machine-learning, rfe

I want to use recursive feature elimination method to select the top features and then put them into machine learning models. I write the code of RFE as

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
results <- rfe(train[,1:134], train[,135], sizes=c(1:134),rfeControl=control)
print(results)
predictors(results)
```

Then the code gives me top features as:
[1] "a"    "b"         "c"            "d"            "e"
and finally I put the features in the model:

```
weighted_fit <- train(x ~ a+b+c+d,
data = train,
method = 'glmnet',
trControl = ctrl)
```

My question is every time that RFE gives me top features as  [1] "a"    "b"         "c"            "d"            "e", I have to edit them as a+b+c+d and put them into the model by hand, however, when there are 50 features selected as top features, it is not possible to edit them and put them into the model, is there any way to do this automatically. I really appreciate your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `help("update")` what you are looking for?

```
x <- rnorm(10)
a <- 1:10
b <- 11:20
c <- 21:30
d <- rnorm(10)

fmla <- x ~ a

update(fmla, "~b")
#x ~ b

new <- c("b", "c", "d")
update(fmla, paste("~", paste(new, collapse = "+")))
#x ~ b + c + d
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.